# Assert context menu using Robolectric

Tags: android, robolectric

The situation is the following:

I have a ListView and when long click is performed on an item a context menu is shown. I've checked it on the emulator but now I want to assert that the context menu appears.

Is there a way to assert that a context menu has been shown using Robolectric?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I've ended implementeing a really basic version of the `public void registerForContextMenu(View view)` like this:

```
view.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onLongClick(View arg0) {
        realActivity.onCreateContextMenu(new TestContextMenu(), null,
            null);
        return true;
    }
});
```

Making a VERY simple implementation of TestContextMenu extending TestMenu and adding a static reference to the last TestContextMenu created by overriding the add and addSubMenu methods.

Answer (score 1):

You can emulate element click and check that `onCreateContextMenu` is called

**UPD**
I wouldn't probably follow my suggestion. What I would do - have two tests:

1. I'll check that after activity creation (or whenever view is added to the activity) the view has correct long click listener
2. And after I would check that code of context menu construction correctly works when is invoked for this specific view

You don't need spying in this approach

Comment: And how do I check that the onCreateContextMenu is called w/o using flags?

Comment: `Mockito.spy` could help you